# Taking integer inputs from user to compute Python function

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the function below, and I'm trying to modify it so that, it takes in Input parameter, "n" from the user.

```
def difference(xs):
    min_elem = xs[0]
    max_elem = xs[0]
    max_diff = -1

    for elem in xs[1:]:
        min_elem = min(elem, min_elem)
        if elem > max_elem:
            max_diff = max(max_diff, elem - min_elem)
            max_elem = elem

    return max_diff
```

Currently it finds the maximum difference within an array. However, I would
like to have a function that can do:

```
difference(n, xs)
```

Meaning, given a number, n (for example n=5) like the following:

```
difference(5, [1,2,3,4,5])
```

the function should simply print out the array numbers line by line, and then output the difference that the function computes.

Comment: Use `[int(input("enter a number: ")) for _ in range(4)]`

Comment: The code you worte is a bit strange, you here seem to do what Python already can do itself: calculating the minimum and maximum of a list, you can write this like `def difference(xs): return max(xs) - min(xs)`.

Comment: So just to clarify: you want the user to decide both on how many inputs they provide and to provide the inputs then?
Your options would be either to first ask how many inputs they want to provide and then use that number in a loop to request the individual inputs, or you could ask the user to directly provide a string representation of a list which you'd then need to parse (though the second option would require more sanitizing depending on how well-behaved your users are)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have edited the question now. It was supposed to print out all the integers as an output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below. Just add one more function `difference_with_input` that will get the inputs from user and call the function that is already written, with the inputs entered.

```
def difference(xs):
    min_elem = xs[0]
    max_elem = xs[0]
    max_diff = -1

    for elem in xs[1:]:
        min_elem = min(elem, min_elem)
        if elem > max_elem:
            max_diff = max(max_diff, elem - min_elem)
            max_elem = elem

    return max_diff

def difference_with_input(n):
    vals = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        vals.append(int(input("Enter value {0} : ".format(i))))
    print(difference(vals))

difference_with_input(5)
```

Output:

```
Enter value 1 : 2
Enter value 2 : 1
Enter value 3 : 3
Enter value 4 : 4
Enter value 5 : 5
4
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, this is a good solution to have, I've also adjusted the question (made a mistake earlier).